# Attribute errors with selectbylocation algorithm

Tags: qgis-processing, qgis-3

Could anybody tell me what is wrong with execution of

```
processing.run('qgis:selectbylocation', layer2, layer, u'intersect', 0)
```

layer2 and layer is QgsVectorLayer object.

This is error message I got

[image]

Comment: Please remember to always provide the error message as ASCII text in the body of the question. This both makes the error legible on all devices and makes it searchable, so others might find question (and, more importantly, your answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using 2.x API, which is not compatible with 3.x. My advice is to run the command you're wanting via the gui, then check the processing history dialog which displays the equivalent python command for that operation. You can then copy this and adapt as required.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [ndawson](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/28443/ndawson) I found solution. Based on processing history dialog i used command

```
    processing.run("native:selectbylocation",
                   {'INPUT': layer2.name(), 'PREDICATE': [0],
                    'INTERSECT': layer.name(), 'METHOD': 0})
```

Additionaly I had to set "Ignore invalid input features" option. Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 1):

There is something wrong with the parameters you provide for processing.run (the error message says that it is expecting something that has an attribute called feedback, but you are providing an integer).

You should check the QGIS 3 API.
See for instance: https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.4/core/Processing/QgsProcessingAlgorithm.html#qgis.core.QgsProcessingAlgorithm.run

You will find some examples in the docs:
https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing/console.html